# Streaming a Map with a nested object in Java8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have an Map of the format

```
Map<Object1, List<Object2>> dependencies;
```

. Can someone please suggest what is the concise way to convert this to a Map<Object1, List < Object3 >> using Java Streams ? Failed attempt to do it with streams is listed below.

```
class Object2 {

List<Object3> subDependencies;

}

//What I was trying to do
Map<Object1, List<Object3>> results = dependencies.entrySet().stream().flatMap
   (entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry.getKey(), Object2::getsubDependecies));
```

Comment: Are you trying to combine all `Object3` in `subDependencies` values as a single list?

Comment: @ernest_k yes. I am trying to combine all subdependencies of Object1 to one map where key is Object1 and Value is list of all the subdependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Map<Object1, List<Object3>> results = 
    dependencies.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                               e -> e.getValue()
                                     .stream()
                                     .map(Object2::getSubDependecies)
                                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                                     .collect(toList())));
```

Comment: seems like you're missing 2 closing brackets at the end of your statement

Comment: @Yoni Right. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @ETO .